# 2009 Mac Pro does not boot after rEFInd

Tags: macos, startup, mac-pro, efi

A few months back, I had a friend install rEFInd on my 2009 Mac Pro so I can use it as a server running a non-GUI version of Ubuntu. Though, after checking it a few months after it’s been off, the rEFInd boot-up manager can not find any macOS instances (only Ubuntu and some “Time Machine” drives). I tried to start the disk up into recovery mode but I got the blinking folder/question mark symbol. I cannot seem to figure out how to boot up macOS on this Mac Pro. Any help?

Comment: Can you post the output from the command `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda`? Run this command from Ubuntu. Also, does macOS appear in the Startup Manager? You can access the Startup Manager by holding down the option key immediately after starting or restarting the Mac.

Comment: This is what shows up from the startup manager: https://ibb.co/3BB9c8k

Comment: The system automatically attempts to start macOS from boot (never finishes loading), so I don't have access to the rEFInd menu to switch to Ubuntu to test that command. How can I access Ubuntu/rEFInd menu?